# opencv with gpu crash in debug mode

Tags: exception, opencv, cuda, gpu

I am using opencv2.4.2 with visual studio 2010 build with cmake (CUDA enabled). The problem is i consistently get a crash when accessing gpu methods/initializations while being in debug mode. It works in release mode although that too needs to be run outside visual studio otherwise some crash occur. The exception that i receive is as follows:

First-chance exception at 0x76dbfbae in opencvGPUtest.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: cudaError_enum at memory location 0x00a3e258

The error is very consistent, and i have seen couple of examples over the internet with others (http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/OpenCV/message/77905). It is very difficult to work without debug support while working with large projects, so kindly help me fix this.

Thanks,

Comment: Did you try to execute opencv_perf_gpud.exe?

Comment: I am using Quadro NVS 140M and yes i ran opencv_perf_gpud although i do not know how to interpret the results. They are OK for some and FAIL for some in imgproc/ getparam().

Comment: It's link opencv and if problem was in opencv itself it'll give you the same error. Did you set `OPENCV_TEST_DATA_PATH`? Come tests need to load some data from your HD.

Answer (score 1):

Encountered the same plroblem, solved by delete all debug/release/x64 files **and the SDF file**.